# Centosでmysqlが起動できない

Tags: mysql

ターミナルでmysqlを起動しようとすると以下のようなエラーが表示されます。
「ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)」

以下の解決法を試しましたが、無理でした。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/TamaC/20090330/1238418696

原因とその解決法を教えてください

Answer (score 3):

エラーメッセージ中の「`(2)`」はエラー番号を表します。
エラー番号の意味を知るには、perror コマンドを実行します。

```
% perror 2
OS error code   2:  No such file or directory
```

つまり、`/tmp/mysql.sock` が無いということです。

考えられるのは、次の原因です。

1. mysqld が起動していない。

   ps コマンドで mysqld が起動しているかどうか確認してみるのがいいと思います。
2. 起動中の mysqld と mysql コマンドが用いる mysql.sock ファイルの場所が異なる。

   mysqld コマンドが用いるソケットファイルは `mysqld --help -v | grep ^socket` で確認できます。